# In the following code, can we make the part fig, ax = plt.subplots() in a separate function?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Can the delimited part below (the part between comments) be encapsulated in a function?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np

def f(t):
    x=np.random.rand(1)
    y=np.random.rand(1)
    return x,y

# From here
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
# To here

def update(t):
    x,y = f(t)
    ax.plot(x, y, marker="s")
    ax.set_title(str(t))

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=100)
plt.show()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the problem is. But the answer is of course yes, anything can be put into a function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np

def f(t):
    x=np.random.rand(1)
    y=np.random.rand(1)
    return x,y

def function():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim(0,1)
    ax.set_ylim(0,1)
    return fig,ax

def update(t):
    x,y = f(t)
    ax.plot(x, y, marker="s")
    ax.set_title(str(t))

fig, ax = function()
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: May I suggest to pass `ax` as a parameter to `update`. I try to include good programming practices in my answers to help newbies get used to them.